# Copy a mysql database from one server to another PHP cron Job automated

Tags: php, mysql, cron

Ok first off this is not a backup job, and I know about using phpmyadmin and so on.

What I have is a Live server and a TEST server, People work on the live one, constantly modifying it. I want the database on the LIVE server to be copied to the TEST server every night.

Does anyone have a php script I could run either to copy down the whole thing (or at least specific tables)? I'm not that confident with using the command line so if there is a way of doing it that way I could do with some pretty specific instructions :P

I have dug around but everyone seems to be suggesting doing it manually or by using third party tools.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You should look into database replication as this does the same but in real time. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/replication-howto.html

Comment: have you looked into an ETL tool like Pentaho PDI: http://kettle.pentaho.com/ ?

Comment: @MarcB Ok dude. Not a helpful comment really. I'm not running a server, I'm using one for a website. That sort of arrogant comment really just doesn't provide any help to anyone.

Comment: @sam I will take a look at that, I think i may want to avoid instant replication as it may be useful to have a'buffer' time limit so that I can recover data if someone screws up :)

Comment: Thought this would be the case hence it being a comment :)

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

In your mysql host machine:

```
1- Create a .sh file
2- Inside of this sh, put:
 - mysqldump -u myuser -p mypass mydatabasename > mydumpfile.sql
 - scp mydumfile.sql user@remote_host:remote_dir
3- Add that sh to a cron Job, to a daily execute
   (or something that meets your requeriments)
```

In the remote machine:

```
1- One sh script that look for a file(mysqldumpfile.sql) in the specific dir
2- This line : mysql -u remotemysqluser -p remotemysqlpass database < mydumpfile.sql
3- rm mydumpfile.sql
4- Add this sh on a daily cron 1 or two hours past the host cron.
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop the test tables -

```
DROP TABLE testdata;
```

And then recreate them as copies of the live tables -

```
CREATE TABLE testdata LIKE livedata;
INSERT INTO testdata SELECT * FROM livedata;
```

This could be done through PHP like this -

```
<?php

$host = '127.0.0.1';
$dbname = 'database'
$user = 'user';
$pass = 'pass';

try {  

  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);  

}

catch(PDOException $e) { 

    echo $e->getMessage(); 

}

$STH = $DBH->('DROP TABLE testdata');
$STH->execute();

$STH = $DBH->('CREATE TABLE testdata LIKE livedata');
$STH->execute();

$STH = $DBH->('INSERT INTO testdata SELECT * FROM livedata');
$STH->execute();

$DBH = null;

?>
```

You can add extra tables as required, but in my example it will make a table called testdata that mirrors the table called livedata.

Then set up a cron job to fire the script when required -

```
php /path/to/script.php
```

Comment: This looks promising. I think  I can see where you are going, will have a try at this as well... thanks for the help

Comment: Ok this seems to be for one server only - I effectively need it across 2  (local and live)